# Object from UIStoryboard become nil if I use setters

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I have some labels on UITableviewcell I want to change the label font in the setter but from some odd reason in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

When I debugging I can see nothing inside the cell get allocated.
When I drop the setters everything work fine but with system font which I don't want to use.

Cell.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CheckoutCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelQuantity;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelMainDescription;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelCountName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelInchSize;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelMMsize;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelStaticTotal;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelTotalPrice;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label_ItemPrice;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnBuyAnotherProduct;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnAddAnotherSet;



@end
```

cell.m file

```
#import "CheckoutCell.h"

@implementation CheckoutCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
-(void) setLabelCountName:(UILabel *)labelCountName
{
    [self setLabel:labelCountName];
     
}
-(void) setLabelMMsize:(UILabel *)labelMMsize
{
    [self setLabel:labelMMsize];

}
-(void) setLabel_ItemPrice:(UILabel *)label_ItemPrice
{
    [self setLabel:label_ItemPrice];
}
-(void) setLabelInchSize:(UILabel *)labelInchSize
{
    [self setLabel:labelInchSize];

}
-(void) setLabelMainDescription:(UILabel *)labelMainDescription
{
    [labelMainDescription setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MuseoSans-500" size:14]];
}
-(void) setLabelQuantity:(UILabel *)labelQuantity
{
    [labelQuantity setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MuseoSans-500" size:18]];
}
-(void) setLabelTotalPrice:(UILabel *)labelTotalPrice
{
    [labelTotalPrice setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MuseoSans-500" size:14]];
}
-(void) setLabelStaticTotal:(UILabel *)labelStaticTotal
{
    [labelStaticTotal setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MuseoSans-500" size:14]];
}
//BTN setters
-(void) setBtnAddAnotherSet:(UIButton *)btnAddAnotherSet
{
    [btnAddAnotherSet.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MuseoSans-500" size:12]];
    btnAddAnotherSet.titleLabel.textAlignment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters;


}
-(void) setBtnBuyAnotherProduct:(UIButton *)btnBuyAnotherProduct
{
    [btnBuyAnotherProduct.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MuseoSans-500" size:12]];
    btnBuyAnotherProduct.titleLabel.textAlignment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters;
   
}

//generic setter
-(void) setLabel:(UILabel *)label
{
    [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MuseoSans-300" size:10]];

}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should just set the text of the label not create and set the label again. for example

```
-(void) setLabelCountName:(UILabel *)labelCountName{
[self setLabel:labelCountName];
```

}

should be

```
-(void) setLabelCountName:(NSString *)labelCountName{
[self.labelCountName setText:labelCountName];
```

}

also you should change the Font in StoryBoard designer or in initWith... method.

Comment: setLabel its the last function it just set the font... and I cant change font inside IB its not Apple font...